# Multiple relationships between the same entities

Tags: database-design, terminology

Is there a name for the case when two entities can have multiple relationships between themselves?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing I know of. Calling it "multiple binary relationships" is acceptable, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to coin a term for it, I'd call the two entities *poly-related* or *poly-relational*.